# Force tax recalculation when TaxZoneID is updated inside event handler

Tags: acumatica

I have a graph override for Invoices

`public class ARInvoiceEntry_Extension : PXGraphExtension<ARInvoiceEntry>`

and in one of the event handlers I am updating `TaxZoneID`, which works fine. However, the taxes do not get updated or recalculated. I have tried the approach mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51844292/programmatically-recalculate-taxes-with-acumatica)

`cache.SetValueExt<SOOrder.taxZoneID>(order, branchLoc.VTaxZoneID);`

but that doesn't work for me. I have tried it in `_FieldUpdating`, `_FieldUpdated`, and even `ARInvoice_RowPersisting(PXCache cache, PXRowPersistingEventArgs e, PXRowPersisting InvokeBaseHandler)` events. Any ideas on why it doesn't work? The TaxZone and rates are already in the database (we are not using Avatax).

--- edit 1 ---

Here is the code where TaxZoneID is updated

```cs
namespace PX.Objects.AR
{
    public class ARInvoiceEntry_Extension : PXGraphExtension<ARInvoiceEntry>
    {
        #region Event Handlers
        protected void ARShippingAddress_PostalCode_FieldUpdated(PXCache sender, PXFieldUpdatedEventArgs e, PXFieldUpdated del)
        {
            // PXTrace.WriteInformation("ARShippingAddress_PostalCode_FieldUpdated");
            ARShippingAddress row = e.Row as ARShippingAddress;

            if (row != null) {
                if (DoChangeTaxZone(row)) {
                    var invoice = Base.Document.Current;

                    if (invoice != null) {
                        invoice.TaxZoneID = GetTaxZoneId(row);

                        sender.SetValueExt<ARInvoice.taxZoneID>(invoice, invoice.TaxZoneID);
                    }
                }
            }

            if (del != null)
            {
                del(sender, e);
            }
        }
        #endregion

        private bool DoChangeTaxZone(ARShippingAddress row)
        {
            // logic ...

            return true;
        }

        private string GetTaxZoneId(ARShippingAddress row)
        {
            // logic ...

            return "TAX-ZONE-ID";
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please add the code where you are updating the TaxZoneID to the question

Comment: You are working with `ARInvoiceEntry` PXGraph and not `SOOrderEntry`, most likely the Tax Engine is reacting to the `ARInvoice`'s `TaxZoneID` and not `SOOrder`'s. Try to `SetValueExt` on `ARInvoice`'s `TaxZoneID`.

Comment: @SamvelPetrosov - I added the code where the update is happening. I did try calling `SetValueExt` on `ARInvoice.taxZoneID` as you can see in the added code, but that doesn't seem to work for some reason. Maybe I'm using the wrong event propagation order?

Comment: It is not straightforward to do so, I'm asking around for an example I've seen before. Someone should post an answer soon.

Answer (score 2):

When you programmatically interact with tax records using the typical methods, the tax total will not refresh properly. The Tax DAC attribute doesn't recalculate the totals by default to improve performance.

To force tax attribute refresh you need to change the tax calc mode.

Tax calc mode `NoCalc` does not recalculate totals. This is the default mode.

Setting tax calc mode to `ManualCalc` is necessary to refresh the updated tax.

Code example to update the tax amount field, you can adapt it to update tax zone.

```
ARInvoiceEntry invoiceMaint = PXGraph.CreateInstance<ARInvoiceEntry>(); 
TX.TaxAttribute.SetTaxCalc<ARTran.taxCategoryID>(invoiceMaint.Transaction.Cache, null, TX.TaxCalc.ManualCalc); 
invoiceMaint.CurrentDocument.Current = invoiceMaint.Document.Search<ARInvoice.refNbr>("AR005452", ARDocType.Invoice).FirstOrDefault(); 
invoiceMaint.Taxes.Select();
invoiceMaint.Taxes.Current = invoiceMaint.Taxes.Search<ARTaxTran.taxID>("CAGST").FirstOrDefault(); 
invoiceMaint.Taxes.Cache.SetValueExt<ARTaxTran.curyTaxAmt>(invoiceMaint.Taxes.Current, 3); 
invoiceMaint.Taxes.Update(invoiceMaint.Taxes.Current);
invoiceMaint.SelectTimeStamp(); 
invoiceMaint.Save.Press();
```